# Persist react-query pagination after unmount

Tags: react-query

So I've got a paginated query that looks like this:

```js
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    search_text: undefined,
    page_size: 10,
    page: 1,
  });

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['users', { filters }],
    queryFn: () => /* some fetch */,
    keepPreviousData: true,
  });
```

My problem is I want to know the last filters used when so when I unmount my component, I can return to it and have the exact same data AND filters. Obviously if I keep the filters as state I lose this state when the component unmounts. I was wondering if react-query can somehow help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a client state problem, react-query can’t really help here. You would need to move that client state up, either to a parent component, a global client state manager like zustand, or eventually the url - which works very well for search queries and pagination because it also gives you shareable urls for free.

Comment: Never considered moving the state to the URL, that's a neat idea.